# Count Complete Cases per Group

Tags: r, function, count

I have a big data set (roughly 10 000 rows), and want to create a function that counts the number of complete cases (not NAs) per group. I tried various functions (aggregate, table, sum(complete.cases), group_by, etc), but somehow I miss one - probably little - trick. Thanks for any help!

A little sample data set to explain, the result I need.

```
x <- data.frame(group = c(1:4), 
                age = c(4:1, c(11, NA,13, NA)), 
                speed = c(12, NA,15,NA))
print(x)
#  group age speed
#1     1   4    12
#2     2   3    NA
#3     3   2    15
#4     4   1    NA
#5     1  11    12
#6     2  NA    NA
#7     3  13    15
#8     4  NA    NA
```

One function I wrote reads as follows:

```
CountPerGroup <- function(group) {
    data.set <- subset(x,group %in% group)

    vect <- vector()
    for (i in 1:length(group)) {
        vect[i] <- sum(complete.cases(data.set))
    }
    output <- data.frame(cbind(group,count=vect))   
    return(output)

}
```

The result of

```
CountPerGroup(2:1)
```

is

```
  group count
1     2     4
2     1     4
```

Unfortunately, this is wrong. Instead the outcome should look like

```
  group count
1     2     1
2     1     4
```

What am I missing? How can I tell R to count of complete.cases **per Group**?
Thank you very much for any help on this!

Comment: sorry, doesn't get me the correct results ... maybe I don't use your line correctly - how would you implement it in the function?

Comment: How do you count 4 complete case of group 1 and 1 complete cases of group 2? Mind you, complete cases are *not* the same thing as the number of non-missing values

Comment: if you have a high number of data, you can also use data.table, this package is often made for this effect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like should do the trick if you wish to maintain your functionality:

```
x <- data.frame(group = c(1:4), 
                age = c(4:1, c(11, NA,13, NA)), 
                speed = c(12, NA,15,NA))

CountPerGroup <- function(x, groups) {
  data.set <- subset(x, group %in% groups)
  ans <- sapply(split(data.set, data.set$group), 
                function(y) sum(complete.cases(y)))
  return(data.frame(group = names(ans), count = unname(ans)))
}


CountPerGroup(x, 1:2)
#  group count
#1     1     2
#2     2     0
```

Which is correct from what I can count. But it does not agree with your suggested outcome.

**EDIT**

It seems that you want the number of non-`NA` instead and correctly sorted. Use this function instead:

```
CountPerGroup2 <- function(x, groups) {
   data.set <- subset(x, group %in% groups)
   ans <- sapply(split(data.set, data.set$group), 
                 function(y) sum(!is.na(y[, !grepl("group", names(y))])))[groups]
   return(data.frame(group = names(ans), count = unname(ans)))
}

CountPerGroup2(x, 2:1)
#  group count
#1     2     1
#2     1     4
```

Comment: the dataset has two rows for group 1 and 2 rows for group two. Group 1 has the four values 4 (age), 11(age), 12 (speed), 12(speed). Group 2 has the value 2 for age, but age in line 6 is NA, and speed has two NAs. So I count 4 values (= observations) for group1 and  value for group 2.

Comment: @user2006697 Aha. So you want the number of observations (i.e. non-missing values). I see, and I'll modified the answer. Do note that this is *not* the same thing as the number of complete cases. A complete case is an entire row with no NAs.

Comment: Ahhhh.... thanks for this explanation ... i obviously misunderstood the complete.cases function. Thanks for this - and for your modified answer!

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a million for your help and patience!

Comment: One more question: this code ignores the sequence of the groups in the function. I.e. it does not matter whether I used CountPerGroup2(x, 1:2) or CountPerGroup2(x, 2:1). How can I change your code such, that it takes the order in the function input into account?

Comment: @user2006697 By sorting the `ans` object after `groups` in the function. I've modified the `CountPerGroup2` function in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for a way to get the full count of non-NA values per group, you could use something like:

```
library(plyr)
x <- data.frame(group = c(1:4), 
                age = c(4:1, c(11, NA,13, NA)), 
                speed = c(12, NA,15,NA))

counts <- ddply(x, "group", summarize, count=sum(!is.na(c(age, speed))))

##   group count
## 1     1     4
## 2     2     1
## 3     3     4
## 4     4     1
```

You do miss out on having a *function* that lets you query a subset of the groups, but you get a one-line way to calculate the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(functional)

countPerGroup = function(x, vec)
{
    dt = data.table(x) 
    d1 = setkey(dt, group)[group %in% vec]
    d2 = d1[,lapply(.SD, Compose(Negate(is.na), sum)),by=group]
    transform(d2, count=age+speed, speed=NULL, age=NULL)
}


countPerGroup(x, 1:2)
#   group count
#1:     1     4
#2:     2     1

countPerGroup(x, c(1,2))
#   group count
#1:     1     4
#2:     2     1
```

If you have a high number of lines in your `data.table`, it is particularly efficient!

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a bit too advanced for me at the moment, but I saved it for the future!

Comment: Compose and Negate are really intuitive functions from functional package, you should have a look!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found an easier solution

library(data.table)

```
x <- data.table(group = c(1:4), 
                age = c(4:1, c(11, NA,13, NA)), 
                speed = c(12, NA,15,NA))
x[,sum(complete.cases(.SD)), by=group]
```